# Comparison between pointer (char*) and integer error

Tags: c, cs50, c-strings

So basically the user inputs how many countries they have visited in a variable, then I take it as the size of the array.

After that I use a `for` loop to list out all the countries visited. But I want to make my code a little smarter and put `and` at the end of the sentence for the final country.

For example `3` countries:

```
You visited Japan, Korea and Canada.
                 ^       ^^^
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>


int main(void)
{
    int number_of_p = get_int("How many countries did you visit?\n");
    string countries[number_of_p];

    for (int x = 0; x < number_of_p; x++)
    {
        countries[x] = get_string("What countries did you visit?\n");
    }
    printf("You visited %i countries, including: ", number_of_p);
    for (int x = 0; x < number_of_p; x++)
    {

        printf("%s, ", countries[x]);
        /* looks for last element in arrays, inserts 'and' 
        to make it look grammatically correct. */

        if (countries[x] == number_of_p - 1 ) // ERROR HERE
        {
            printf(" and ");
        }

    }
    printf(".\n");

}
```

I'm getting a comparison between pointer (`char*`) and integer error.

What does `char*` mean?

How do I access the last element in an array?

Comment: `x` is your index. That's what you want to check agaist. `countries[x]` is a string. i.e. `if (countries[x] == number_of_p - 1 )` should be `if (x == number_of_p - 1 )`.

Comment: but i am checking against x, i did if countries[x] == number_of_p - 1 then print f. so like take countries and it's equal to the size variable minus 1 then print out 'and' with a space. also i have a question. wtf does char* mean? i used a string not a char. also what does the * do, i looked up it means pointer but what does  char* have to do with this and why am i getting pointer and int comparison error. please explain clearly cuz im a stupid beginner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`countries[x]` is a `string` (which in `CS50` is a typedef of `char*`), `number_of_p` is an `int`, you can't compare them, they are different types, you may have wanted to compare the index `x`, a possible (and quick) fix for your code, including the punctuation could look like this:

[**Live demo**](https://godbolt.org/z/4b3qM9eoq)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number_of_p = get_int("How many countries did you visit?\n");
    string countries[number_of_p];

    for (int x = 0; x < number_of_p; x++)
    {
        countries[x] = get_string("What countries did you visit?\n");
    }
    printf("You visited %i countries, including: ", number_of_p);
    for (int x = 0; x < number_of_p; x++)
    {

        printf("%s", countries[x]);
        if(x < number_of_p - 2){
            printf(", ");
        }
   
        if (x == number_of_p - 2)
        {
            printf(" and ");
        }  
    }
    printf(".\n");
}
```

Input:

```
3
Japan
Korea
Canada
```

Output:

```
You visited 3 countries, including: Japan, Korea and Canada.
```

Comment: i'm really confused by your code. why are you doing if(x < number_of_p - 2) {printf(", ");, what is this doing? printing a comma between each country? why is that if statement necessary if you already have a for loop that is contantly evaluating if x is less than number_of_p, can't you just do printf(" ,"; after printf("%s", countries[x]); also why do you do number_of_p - 2 and not number_of_p - 1?

Comment: second, why are you doing if (x == number_of_p - 2) {printf(" and"}, again why isn't it number_of_p - 1? and lastly, i'm so confused. wouldn't this just print 'and' at the end of the sentence and not print the last country. don't you need another statement like printf("%s", countries[x]" at the end of the loop? otherwise wouldn't you just get 'japan korea canada and"  because you left out that last print statement?

Comment: @ShahJacob so you don't want to print a coma after the 2 last countries are printed, after the penultimum you want `and` and after the last one you don't want nothing, so that you can print a full stop. Makes sense?

Comment: @ShahJacob, beacause you print the country first and next the comma, you'd want the last 2 countries to not have a comma after. So Korea and Canada don't need the comma after.

Comment: @ShahJacob You have to remember that indexes start at `0`, `countries[0]`, `countries[1]` and `countries[2]`. We print `countries[0]` and comma, `countries[1]` will not need a comma, neither will  `countries[2]`, `number_of_p - 2` is `1`, so after printing `countries[1]`, (`if x == 1`)  we print `and`, see what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

The condition in the if statement

```
    if (countries[x] == number_of_p - 1 )
```

does not make a sense. The left operand `countries[x]` has the type `char *`  while the right operand has the type `int`.

That is the type specifier `string` is an alias for the type `char *` and this declaration of an array

```
string countries[number_of_p];
```

is the same as

```
char * countries[number_of_p];
```

So you have an array of pointers that point to strings.

The alias `string` for the type `char *` in C defined the following way

```
typedef char * string;
```

The loop can look like

```
for (int x = 0; x < number_of_p; x++)
{
    if ( x != 0 )
    {
        putchar( ',' );
        putchar( ' ' );

        if ( x ==  number_of_p - 1 )
        {
            printf( "%s ", "and " );
        }
    }
    printf("%s", countries[x]);
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { number_of_p = 3 };
    char *countries[number_of_p] =
    {
        "Japan", "Korea", "Canada"
    };
    
    printf( "You visited %i countries, including: ", number_of_p );
    
    for (int x = 0; x < number_of_p; x++)
    {
        if ( x != 0 )
        {
            putchar( ',' );
            putchar( ' ' );

            if ( x ==  number_of_p - 1 )
            {
                printf( "%s ", "and" );
            }
        }
        printf("%s", countries[x]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
You visited 3 countries, including: Japan, Korea, and Canada
```

Comment: im confused, what does char* mean. and what is the difference between char* and char. i know strings in C are basically arrays of type char, but what does char* mean and what does it do. also why does my if statement make sense.

Comment: also im a beginner C programmar and i dont know what *countries[number_of_p] does. is that a pointer? why are you using a pointer at an index of an array. sorry i dont really know how pointers work i just started programming in C a month ago. also what does enum do and what is put char. can you please answer all of my questions please im so confused and frustrated

Comment: @ShahJacob The type specifier string used in your program is an alias for the type char *. You are entering strings and pointers to their first characters are returned by the function  get_string.

Comment: @ShahJacob This declaration string countries[number_of_p]; is the same as teh declaration char * countries[number_of_p];

Comment: i dont understand anything you just said please explain with more simple words. what does type specificer string and alias mean. and what does entering strings and pointers to their first characters returned by the function get_string mean.

Comment: also can you explain my original questions please. what is the difference between char* and char. i know * is the pointer symbol but why are pointers being used here. also in his code what does enum and put char do what is their purpose. also what's the logic of if ( x != 0), what does that do?. and why does his code when he writes if countries[x] = size_of_p work but mine doesnt work?

Comment: @ShahJacob You may consider the type specifier string as an synonym for the type char *.

Comment: can you please just answer my questions if you dont mind. first what does *char mean and why is the right side *char, it is a string not a char. second why are you doing *char countries instead of string countries. third what is the purpose of the if statement if (x != 0)  {putchar (','); putchar(' '), why is this if statement being used. lastly why are you doing if x = size_of_p - 1 as opposed to countries[x], can you please explain

Comment: @ShahJacob You need a book on C for beginners. The condition if ( x != 0 ) means that before outputting the first string you should not output a comma.

Comment: can you please explain the logic first?  what is the logic of doing (if x != 0) do. also why do you if (x = number_of_p - 1) instead of countries[x] = number_of_p - 1, why use x instead of number_of_p

Comment: please explain the logic behind that initial if statement at the for loop. also why do you use put char after that initial if statement. why do you use if (x != 0) before the second if statement. and i cant find any good books on C. can you just help me and answer all of my questions first. also what did that statement 'entering strings and pointers to their first characters returned by the funtion get_string' mean. latly what does alias mean. again please make sure to explain the if statement. i really need your help and will find a book on C later, i need to do this HW now first

Answer (score 0):

You can do this sort of thing with one printf, using a predefined string for the separator.  Using a single printf rather than special casing the tail of the list is generally easier to maintain.  Many people find the ternary operator confusing; here's the approach in two different ways, using a switch first and the ternary operator second:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        char *countries[] = { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
        int number_of_p = sizeof countries / sizeof *countries;
        /* First loop, using a switch */
        for( int x = 0; x < number_of_p; x++ ) {
                char *div = ", ";
                switch( x ){
                case sizeof countries / sizeof *countries - 2: div = ", and "; break;
                case sizeof countries / sizeof *countries - 1: div = ".\n"; break;
                }
                printf("%s%s", countries[x], div);
        }
        /* Same loop as above, with if/else instead of the switch */
        for( int x = 0; x < number_of_p; x++ ) {
                char *div = ", ";
                if( x == number_of_p - 2 ) {
                        div = ", and ";
                } else if( x == number_of_p - 1 ) {
                        div = ".\n";
                }
                printf("%s%s", countries[x], div);
        }
        /* Same loop as above, written less verbosely */
        for( int x = 0; x < number_of_p; x++ ) {
                printf("%s%s", countries[x], x == number_of_p - 2 ? ", and " :
                        x == number_of_p - 1 ? ".\n" : ", ");
        }
}
```

Comment: sorry what does *countries] = {foo, bar, baz} mean. specifically what does *countries[] mean, i know * is a pointer symbol but i just started programming in C and dont know how pointers work. why are you using the pointer symbol when declaring an array. also why are you using double quotes instead of single quotes since it's a char. and also why are you doing size of countries / size of *countries, what does *countries mean. what is the function of *countries why are you using a pointer. please explain please

Comment: The `char *countries[] = { "foo", "bar", "baz" }` is just a way to initialize the array.  Your user input is not particularly relevant to my solution, so I'm omitting it all for clarity.   The double quotes are there because `countries` is *not* a char, it is an array of pointer to char.  "foo" is a constant string to which the first element of the `countries` array is being assigned.  The `sizeof countries / sizeof *countries` is a standard technique for getting the number of elements of an array.

Comment: `sizeof` is a compile time operator (not a function), and `sizeof countries` is the size of the full array.  On my box, a char * is size 4.  Since there are 3 elements of the array, sizeof countries is 12.  `sizeof *countries` is the size of one of the elements, so `sizeof countries / sizeof *countries` is 3.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot use a variable in the cases of the switch statement, but you can use the compile time constant.  That limitation is why I tend to prefer the ternary operator embedded in the printf for this type of thing.  It's cleaner (IMO) than a long list of if statements.

Comment: i am quite confused by what you mean. how is countries not a char. also dont you mean string instead of char. secondly why are you using *char, what is the function of *char, what is the function of using pointer * symbol here here (we havent learned pointers uet). second why are you using double quotes instead of single quote if its a char. 3rd why does sizeof coountries / size of *countries work. why are you using *countries, why are you using a pointer here. what size_of countries / size of countries even mean, it's literally the same statement divided by the same statement? can you explain

Comment: `char *countries[]` declares countries to be an array of type "pointer to char".  A pointer to char is not a char.  It is a pointer to char.  It is common to think of "pointer to char" as a "string", but that is not technically correct.  It probably won't hurt too much to think of them as the same thing.

Comment: `* countries` is not a pointer.  The `*` operator dereferences the pointer.  Consider the declarations `int x; int *y = &x; x = 5`.  In this, `y` is a pointer to int. `*y` is an int.  `y` is the address of x. `*y` is 5.  Similarly, `*countries` is "foo".  `sizeof *countries` is the size of a `char *`.  `sizeof countries` is the size of the array.  But the sizeof operators are not at all important to your original question: just replace `sizeof operator / sizeof *operators` with `number_of_p`.   It is the number of elements in the array.

Comment: what does pointer to char mean. like conceptually what does it mean. why are pointers being involved and what does char *countries[] do. also your c code is too advanced for me to understand i just started learning last month we havent learned pointers yet can you comment your code and break it down. what does printf("%s%s", countries[x], x == number_of_p - 2 ? ", and " :
                        x == number_of_p - 1 ? ".\n" : ", "); do?, this is too advanced for me. me. what is that second argument x == number_of_p - 2 ? doing. and what do the : and ? symbols do. please explain im a beginner

Comment: can you explain what those ? and : symbols are doing. also why are you writing ', and ' after the two arguments in the print f function. and then why are you doing x == number_of_p_2 first and then x==number_of-p - 1 later. finally, why are you not using an if statement and just a for loop. PLEASE answer all of my questions. i am total beginner and your code is wayy to complex and hard for me to follow and i really wanna understand. im so confused by that printf statement and those arguments in that statement and what the : and ? symbols are doing

Comment: I've edited the answer to provide an if/else chain.  The ternary operator `?:` can be thought of as a condensed `if/else`.  `x = exp ? val1 : val2` is (basically) the same is `if( exp ) x = val1; else x = val2;`, but it can be use on the RHS of an expression.

Comment: A "pointer to char" is a variable that contains the address of a char.  `char *countries[] = ...` defines `countries` as an array of pointers to char.  `"foo"` is a string literal that can be thought of as an array of 4 chars.  If you want to print it, you pass the address of the `f` to `printf`.

Comment: i dont really understand any of your answers, can you please explain simply and clearly. what does ? and : do. you didnt use ?: together you used them separately spaced out. can you explain the logic of printf("%s%s", countries[x], x == number_of_p - 2 ? ", and " : x == number_of_p - 1 ? ".\n" : ", "); it is way too advanced for me to understand. 1st) what does that second argument number_of_p -  2in the printf do, why are you subtracting by 2. 2nd, what does : x == number_of_ P- 1 do?? also why do you a second question mark after number_of_p - 1..? and why subtract by 2 and then 1.

Comment: also what does 'char *countries[] defines countries as an array of pointers to char mean. why is using an array of pointers to char useful, why dont you just use string. why are pointers/memory locations involved. im just so confused by how pointers work / why they're needed and why you have to use an array of pointers to char, what does that statement even mean. an array of pointers to what char? why is memory/memory addresses involved? please explain man

Comment: In my example, there are three strings: "foo", "bar", and "baz".  To reference a string, you need a pointer to the first element: a pointer to char.  To refer to three 3 strings, you need an array of 3 items.  Each of those items is a pointer to char (think of it as a "string").  After you print the first item, you print ", ".  After you print the 2nd item, (index 1 == 3 - 2),  you print ", and".  After you print the 3rd item, (index 2 == 3 - 1), you print ".\n".  I don't know how I can make it any more clear.  Ignore the ternary operator if it is confusing you.